# Allowing users to change password-based sso password

Tags: azure, passwords, single-sign-on, reset, azure-active-directory

Using AzureAD, users can log in through https://portal.office.com/myapps to their assigned apps. Some of them use the password-based sso with the option "User manages credentials".

This works fine, the user gets a question for his password and this password is used for SSO. Exept when this password changes or is mistyped the first time, then the user can't change his own saved credentials unless two factor authentication is activated for this user.

What is the best way to let the initial password prompt reappear for an user, or give another way to reset the password without activating 2FA?

Answer (score 1):

To answer my own question, there are two portals, the Office 365 version at https://portal.office.com/myapps and the Azure version at https://myapps.microsoft.com. At the second portal, you can click on the three dots and select "update credentials". This can only be done by the users themselves.

Another way, is via the Azure admin portal. There you can assign permissions to an app. We do this normally based on groups. If you assign the permission individually, you can set or change the password, but also empty the fields. This way the user will be re-prompted for their password. After this, you can delete the individual permission, so it's again only group assigned. This can only be done by an admin.

Comment: The myapps-link is exactly what I was looking for. Any logged in user can go and update own settings there.